# Problemas no insert utilizando php

Tags: php, mysql

Eu gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, estou tentando fazer uma insert simples com php e mysql mas estou dando 3 erros, que já descobri que são a conexão, só que eu dou o include na conexao(que é um arquivo externo) e mesmo assim os erros estão lá, por favor o que estou fazendo de errado?
Este é o arquivo php que estou fazendo o insert

```
<?php
 include "conexao.php";     
 if(@$_GET["go"] == "cadastrar"){
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    if(empty($nome)){
        echo "<script>window.alert('Devem ser preencidos todos os campos para realizar o cadastro!'); history.back();</script>";
    }
    elseif(empty($email)){
        echo "<script>window.alert('Devem ser preencidos todos os campos para realizar o cadastro!'); history.back();</script>";
    }
    elseif(empty($usuario)){
        echo "<script>window.alert('Devem ser preencidos todos os campos para realizar o cadastro!'); history.back();</script>";
    }
    elseif(empty($senha)){
        echo "<script>window.alert('Devem ser preencidos todos os campos para realizar o cadastro!'); history.back();</script>";
    }
    else{
        $query = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE USUARIO = '$usuario'"));
        if($query == 1){
            echo "<script>window.alert('Usuário já existente!'); history.back();</script>";
        }else{
            mysqli_query("insert into cadastro(nome,email,usuario,senha) values('$nome','$email','$usuario','$senha')");
            //echo "<script>window.alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');</script>";
            //echo "<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content = '0,url = 'principal.php'>";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

E abaixo o arquivo de conexao

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$banco = "bancoteste";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario, $senha);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Não foi possível a conexão com o servidor de dados! Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: "e mesmo assim os erros estão lá" – mas quais são os erros? inclua as mensagens de erro na pergunta usando o link de [edit].

Comment: O PDO e o MySQLi não se comunicam... no `myqli_query()`  precisa passar dois argumentos o primeiro é a conexão (MySQLi) e o segundo a consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma conexão PDO não funciona com a biblioteca MySQLi, então o include não está certo. O outro problema é que faltou passar a conexão para o `mysqli_query()` que faz o insert.

Seu arquivo de conexão deve ficar dessa forma:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
```

Mude:

```
mysqli_query("insert into cadastro(nome,email,usuario,senha)  values('$nome','$email','$usuario','$senha')");
```

Para:

```
mysqli_query($con, "insert into cadastro(nome,email,usuario,senha) values('$nome','$email','$usuario','$senha')");
```

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você está misturando `PDO` com `mysqli_query` são coisas distintas.

para usar o `PDO` sua query que está assim `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE USUARIO = '$usuario'")` teria de estar assim `foreach($con->query("SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE USUARIO = '$usuario'") as $row){}`

da uma olhada na doc que acho que facilita php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.connections.php e secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php

Eu fiz um objeto simples de conexão com o banco que usei muito você pode baixar no php classes https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9400-PHP-Execute-common-SQL-queries-using-MySQLi-extension.html

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda